# DOM node child collections--what's the difference?

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes

What's the difference between the children and childNodes collections of a node? And childElementCount and childNodes.length?

Comment: Note that you're speaking of DOM nodes, not JS nodes.

Comment: @outis: What do you mean by JS node?

Comment: @Gumbo: nothing. The original question referred to "JS nodes".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`element.childNodes` and `element.childNodes.length`: includes child elements, text nodes (including whitespace nodes between elements) and comments (plus potentially CDATASections, ProcessingInstructions, DocumentTypes and EntityReferences, depending on the document and parser). Defined by the [DOM Level 1 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#attribute-childNodes) standard and has been available on every browser for many years.

`element.children` and `element.childElementCount`: includes *only* element nodes, so can be simpler to handle in some cases. `childElementCount` is defined by the [Element Traversal API](http://www.w3.org/TR/ElementTraversal/#attribute-childElementCount) standard and is available in the latest versions of Mozilla, Opera and WebKit. `children` is not defined by any standard, but is available in IE and up-to-date versions of Mozilla, Opera, WebKit and IE.

Comment: Point of clarification; I believe `childElementCount` is available now in IE version 9 and (presumably) above.

Answer (score 2):

Children contains only elements. ChildNodes contains all nodes.