# Counting the number of child elements after dynamically appendChild

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to count the number of child nodes dynamically appended to a parent node as below. The property `childElementCount` does not work. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container')
for (var i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
  let containerChild = document.createTextNode('1')
   container.appendChild(containerChild)
}    
alert("Children count: " + container.childElementCount)
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: The value returned by `childElementCount` contains the number of child element nodes, not the number of all child nodes (like text and comment nodes).

Comment: `container.childNodes.length` is probably what you want

Comment: elements and nodes are different .

Comment: @SandrinJoy Thanks for the tip. Now I need to check out the differences between the two.

Comment: @TristanTran every (i beleive) element in the DOM is a Node. nodes that refer to a html elements are elements too. your `TextNodes` are nodes and not elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `childNodes.length` instead of `childElementCount`:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container')
for (var i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
  let containerChild = document.createTextNode('1')
   container.appendChild(containerChild)
}
alert("Children count: " + container.childNodes.length)
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

See more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2260618/11293963

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a HTML element

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container')
for (var i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
  let containerChild = document.createTextNode('1')
    var node = document.createElement("span");
    node.appendChild(containerChild); 
   container.appendChild(node)
}    

  alert("Children count: " +document.getElementById('container').childElementCount)
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Gail Thanks for answering. I am going with NickSlash's solution since it is more generic.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
const container = document.getElementById('container')
let count = 0;
for (var i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
  let containerChild = document.createTextNode('1')
   container.appendChild(containerChild)
   count ++
}    
alert("Children count: " + count)
```

Comment: Israyekyan Thanks. My node list needs to be accessed elsewhere in someone else's code. So maintaining a variable ```count``` is not quite convenient.